# Correcting the position of a icon in an button that's animated on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to animate an email button on hover.  Everything works fine, except that the mail icon moves to the center when it's hovered over.  It should remain to the left of the text in essentially its starting position.  I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.  Here's a link to my Codepen and also my css.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Qsbrown3/pen/YzyVjjN

Css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #111111;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100;

}

section {
  padding: 6rem;
}

/*Start email icon*/
#container {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: .1% 10%;
}

#learn-more {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
}
#learn-more {
  width: 20rem;
  height: auto;
}
#learn-more #circle {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background: #dadada;
  border-radius: 2.625rem;
}
#learn-more #circle #icon {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;

  background: #fff;
}

i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  top:25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
}


#learn-more #circle #icon#arrow {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);

  background: none;
}
#learn-more #circle #icon#arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
}
#learn-more #button-text {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 1.85rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: center;
}
#learn-more:hover #circle {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
#learn-more:hover #circle #icon{
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translate(1rem, 0);
          transform: translate(1rem, 0);
}
#learn-more:hover #button-text {
  color: #fff;
}

/*End email icon*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two changes to `i` tag's styles. Please check.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #111111;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100;

}

section {
  padding: 6rem;
}

/*Start email icon*/
#container {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: .1% 10%;
}

#learn-more {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
}
#learn-more {
  width: 20rem;
  height: auto;
}
#learn-more #circle {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  background: #dadada;
  border-radius: 2.625rem;
}
#learn-more #circle #icon {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;

  background: #fff;
}

i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  top:25%;
  left: 10px; //changed
  //width: 50%; // removed
}


#learn-more #circle #icon#arrow {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);

  background: none;
}
#learn-more #circle #icon#arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
}
#learn-more #button-text {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 0 1.85rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: center;
}
#learn-more:hover #circle {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
#learn-more:hover #circle #icon{
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translate(1rem, 0);
          transform: translate(1rem, 0);
}
#learn-more:hover #button-text {
  color: #fff;
}

/*End email icon*/
```